# Is there any source which provides raw DNS archive log data?

Tags: dns, raw-data

Could anyone help me in finding any source which provides raw DNS log data. I don't want processed DNS logs. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given any specifics: what OS, what DNS software you're running.  I'll throw some random stuff out there to answer your vague question, and hope for the best.

You can't get any more raw in your logs than tcpdump.  This is kind of a brutal solution that uses lots of CPU and disk space.  If this is what you really want, and your name server isn't that active, you have a short window of time that you want to debug a specific problem, then this might be for you.

as root, do something like this, and you'll save all traffic destined to your dns server: 
set the INTERFACE and MYSERVERIP variables as appropriate...

```
MYSERVERIP=10.0.0.1
INTERFACE=eth0
tcpdump -nn -i $INTERFACE -s 0 -c 100000 -w foo.cap port 53 and dst $MYSERVERIP
```

This will store 100,000 dns queries into the file foo.cap

You can get a brief summary of the dns traffic with `tcpdump -nn -r foo.cap` 
You can get a fully exploded super-detailed view of the dump file with `tshark -nn -r foo.cap -V`